# Efficiently checking if number is in range of 2nd number +-10%?

Tags: python

I need to write a function which checks if a number is in range of `10%` from another number.

I wrote this function:

```
def IsCloseEntough(num1, num2 ):
    percent = num1/100
    if num1-percent < num2 and num2< num1+percent:
       return True;
    else:
       return False;
```

It returns `True` if  `num1-10% of num1 < num2 < num1+10%`. This solves the problem however it feels like this code isn't very "Python Like". Is there a way to make it simpler?

Comment: you can do `return abs(num1 - num2) < 0.1 * num1`

Comment: @Drjnker mate you should answer it :)

Comment: you can do also: `1 - (num1 / float(num2)) < 0.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
def IsCloseEnough(num1, num2 ):
     return abs(float(num1 - num2) / float(num1)) < 0.1
```

Comment: Look out for division by zero when doing this.

Answer (score 8):

[**PEP 0485**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/) introduced the **[`math.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)** function (and it's complex cousin **[`cmath.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.isclose)** for making these sort of checks; it also checks for special values such as `NaN`, `Inf` et al. *The apparent downside is,* it **only** appears in `Python 3.5` from what I know and it's still in it's infancy so it might get some face-lifts in the future.

Basic functionality:

```
math.isclose(1, 1.09, abs_tol=0.1)
Out[20]: True

math.isclose(1.0, 1.2, abs_tol=0.1)
Out[23]: False

math.isclose(1.0, 0.9, abs_tol=0.1)
Out[24]: True
```

This is a built-in (so you could use it efficiently with things like `filter()` ) that's made to check how close two numerics are and allows for greater flexibility when trying to find approximations.

Internally it uses the `abs` solutions in a similar manner presented here, take a look at the [**`C` source**](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1994) for yourself, it is most likely as efficient as it can get. (A version of it python can be found [`here`](https://github.com/PythonCHB/close_pep/blob/master/is_close.py))

For older versions of Python, you could use the solutions already pointed out or look at how `math.isclose()` was implemented and get inspired.

---

Note that in most cases `rel_tol` should be specified, unless dealing with values near `0`. Additionally, for cases where array elements should be evaluated, the most efficient use is probably supplied by the **[`numpy.isclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy-isclose)** function.

Comment: Wouldn't using `rel_tol=0.1` be more appropriate here than `abs_tol`? Sure, for `num1=1` it's the same, but in the general case...

Answer (score 5):

I think the clearest way is very close to your function, with a few alterations:

- you check whether the number is within 1%, not within 10%
- you can use comparison chaining
- you can directly return the result, instead of using an `if/else`

Like this:

```
def isCloseEnough(num1, num2):
    return num1 * 0.9 < num2 < num1 * 1.1
```